# Did other alien races ascend?

Tags: stargate

Do we ever hear or find evidence in the Stargate series that other alien races ascended. I know that a goa'uld once ascended but with help!

Do we know of anyone else that was able to ascend except the people that were helped to do it? Because from what I know only the alterens are the only people we know of that ascended?

Answer (score 8):

The strong implication is that while the ranks of [the Ascended](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ascension) include the Alterans, they aren't *limited* to just the Ancients.

In the SG1 episode '[Threads](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s8/transcripts/818.shtml)', Daniel visits an "Astral Diner" populated by ascended beings. It seems that the ancient Alterans aren't in the majority there:

> **JACKSON** (straightening up to face her): *Why not? Who are they?*
>
> **OMA:** *Others. You're not one of them yet.*
>
> **JACKSON:** *You mean Ancients.*
>
> **OMA:** *A couple of them.*

---

Within the wider canon, a couple of aliens are known to have successfully ascended **on their own**

[Ran](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ran) - An Asgard

[The Orisha](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Orisha) - Energy-based creatures

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of the known Ascended [here](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ascension#Known_Ascended). Excluding Ancients and Alterans, there are still a few:

- Adria (human-Ori hybrid)
- Anubis (gou'ald, partially ascended)
- Chaya Sar (Lantean)
- Dr. Daniel Jackson (Tau'ri, de-Ascended)
- Ran (Asgard, de-Ascended)
- Dr. Elizabeth Weir (Tau'ri, de-Ascended)

Comment: Weir, Jackson and Adria are all the same race. Anubis had help ascending, as did Weir and Jackson. Adria did it on her own but was in an advanced human body. Ran is the only alien in this list who managed it on their own

Comment: Chaya Sar was carrying the [ancient's genes](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Chaya_Sar)